# Probability: PMF PDF Notation used on Wiki question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a question on the following notation used on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability#Definition):

a)
$$
p(\theta|x) = \frac{p(x|\theta)}{p(x)}p(\theta)
$$
where $p(x)$ is the normalizing constant and is calculated as

b)
$$
p(x) = \int p(x|\theta)p(\theta)d\theta
$$
for continuous $\theta$,
or by summing $p(x|\theta)p(\theta)$
over all possible values of $\theta$ for discrete $\theta$
$$

**Question** is this in the correct notation?  I believe $p(x)$ is the PDF or PMF.  The typical notation I have seen for this form is $\rho_X(a), P(X =a| Y = y)$ or $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$

**Question** is this substitution valid?  $p(\theta|X) = f_{\theta|X=x}(t)$

It appears Wiki also uses [this notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability#Calculation) to describe the same, which appears in a more familiar form.

Comment: I have not seen $\rho_X(a)$ with *rho* as an alternative to $p_X(a)$ or $f_X(a)$.  I have seen $\pi(\theta \mid x)$ for the posterior density or mass function for the parameter with $\pi_0(\theta)$ for the prior.  But the notation does not matter much so long as the intention is clear

Comment: I think you're correct, $\rho$ should be $p$.  Do you have any idea of intention for $p(X|Y)$ as per above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question** is this in the correct notation?

No, not really.   The function should properly be subscripted to indicate the random variable, but they leave that job to the parameter.   It is a lazy shorthand to save typespace, since this isn't a formal presentation but intended to convey the basic idea.   (I don't like it, but it's been employed for eons.)

In the same way, they use the integration notation in a more generalised sense: to represent to integration for continuous random variables, or summation for discrete random variables.  The function being used is of course whichever mass or density measure is relevant.